# convert epoch to time_t

Tags: c++, epoch

I have a epoch in double and need to pass in to a function that takes time_t.  How do I convert the epoch in double to time_t?  I am on Linux with C++ code.  Thanks.

Comment: I think he means the "number of seconds elapsed since 00:00:00 on January 1, 1970, Coordinated Universal Time."

Comment: Could you give us an example of the epoch?

Comment: "epoch" represents a time reference, not an arbitrary time. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: @jason, that may be the dictionary definition but it doesn't seem to be the way queandans is using the term.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the epoch in `double`, shouldn't this work?

```
time_t t = static_cast<time_t>(epoch_time);
```

Assuming you mean that the epoch is the

> > number of seconds elapsed since 00:00:00 on January 1, 1970, Coordinated Universal Time.

Comment: 00:00:00 Jan 1 1970 UCT *is* the UNIX epoch, which is a fixed reference instant in time. The number of seconds *since* the epoch is a time and is not itself an epoch.