# How do I set a C++ time_t object to the epoch?

Tags: c++, datetime, stl

This question is similar to the following:

[convert epoch to time_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216139/convert-epoch-to-time-t)

[Converting time_t to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483974/converting-time-t-to-int)

but I don't quite have my answer there.

If you want to get the *current* date/time you can call `time(0)` or `time(NULL)` like in the following standard example:

```
// current date/time based on current system
   time_t now = time(0);
```

I want to define a function which will return a time_t and allows the client to pass an optional default return value in the event of an error.  Further, I want to set a default on that "default" argument.  This provides symmetry within a library I have with one-to-one counter parts across several languages, so I'm not looking to redesign all that.

My thought was to set the default return to the epoch.  Then, a client could in theory easily evaluate that return, and decide that an epoch coming back was more than likely (if not always) an indication of it being invalid.  I can think of some alternatives, but nothing clean, that also fits my existing patterns.

Is there a short and sweet way to make my function signature have a default value for this object equal to the epoch?  For instance

```
   ...myfunc(...., const time_t &defVal=time(0) );
```

would be perfect if `0` meant the epoch rather than the current date/time!

Comment: Use boost optional or std optional instead of flag values.  Please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is wrong with using `0`?  `(time_t)0` represents the epoch itself (if you want to find the actual epoch date/time, pass `(time_t)0` to `gmtime()` or `localtime()`).

```
time_t myfunc(...., time_t defVal = 0 );
```

Or, you could use `(time_t)-1` instead, which is not a valid time, as `time()` returns `(time_t)-1` on error, and `time_t` represents a **positive** number of seconds since the epoch.

```
time_t myfunc(...., time_t defVal = (time_t)-1 );
```

Either way provides the user with something that is easily compared, if they don't provide their own default value.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going with your -1 suggestion.  That is better than 0.  That happily compiled too.

Answer (score 4):

The function `std::time()` returns the number of seconds since the epoch as a `std::time_t`. Therefore to find *zero* seconds after the epoch set `std::time_t` to zero:

```
std::time_t t = 0;
```

So you could do something like:

```
void myfunc(const std::time_t& defVal = 0)
```

Comment: Excellent.  I failed to understand that I could just assign an std::time_t to 0.  This answered my question as posted.  I'm giving the edge to Remy though, for his suggestion of using -1, which is better than my original plan.